# How to push just one specific patch in Mercurial Queues?

Tags: mercurial, patch, mercurial-queue

This is what I did :

```
hg init
hg qnew -m "p1" p1.patch
; some changes
hg qrefresh
hg qpop
hg qnew -m "p2" p2.patch
; some changes
hg qrefresh
hg qpop
```

Now those 2 patches were separate features and have nothing to do with each other. They need to be independent of each other.

Now I do (because I want only the 1st feature)

```
hg qpush p1.patch
```

It says :

```
applying p2.patch
applying p1.patch
```

and it gives me **both** the changes I made !

Am I doing something wrong?

It pushes other patches also when I tell it to push a specific patch.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950784/mercurial-working-with-queues-similar-to-shelves

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot one thing: set of MQ-patches is **queue** (FIFO queue). I.e if you can see more than one patch in `hg qseries`, you have to remember - qpush|qpop will apply|unapply patches not in random order, but in sequential order: push from bottom to top, pop in reverse order

Random access (and changing order of patches in a series as side effect) is `--move` option for qpush. In your case (using only one patch at a time) and patches names

- `hg qpop -a`
- `hg qpush --move p1.patch`
- `hg qpop -a`
- `hg qpush --move p2.patch`

In order to avoid mistakes you can redefine qpush (for this repository) in aliases section for always use `--move` option

Comment: Although, I don't see why HG does it this way. What difference does popping do if all the patches in sequence are applied anyway?

Comment: @learner - **not all** in my commands-set. Single pushed will be applied only (test it on toy-repo). I qpop all just due to own habits